# Iphone Unit Testing error : permission denied with google toolBox

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, toolbox, permission-denied

I followed many tutorial to set up a unit testing project for Iphone but i always get the same "permission denied" error when i build the project.

Here is what i do :

1. Get the latest source for Iphone Unit Testing
2. Follow the instruction to set up the unit testing framework (Create a new project, add a new target, copy the necessary toolbox files into my project, add the script to my target, etc)
3. Build the project (Emulator closed)

I expected :
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.001 (0.001) seconds

But i have the following error :

/vdaTest/Calculation/build/Calculation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/unitTest.build/Script-7BDF2E1A10172C2000279979.sh: line 2: /vdaTest/googleToolBox/RuniPhoneUnitTest.sh: Permission denied

I'm using this version of the toolBox:
Revision 158: /trunk

On :
Mac OS X version 10.5.7

I'm using Xcode 3.1.3 with Iphone simulator 3.0

I've search here and on google for that error but i didn't find anything... Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Vincent.

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks to the xcode-users mailing list! This solution works on my mac:

```
chmod +x RunIPhoneUnitTest.sh
```

This might do the trick. "Permission denied" is the error you get when you try to tun a shell script that is not executable.